# Why $\mathbb Q^n$ is not a lattice of $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

We can show that $\mathbb Z^n$, additive subgroup of $\mathbb R^n$, is a lattice and intuitively see that it might not be possible to generate $\mathbb Q^n$ as integral multiple of $m$, $m\leq n$, linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb R^n$. But can you give a proof, I am having difficulty grasping the definition of lattices itself.

Comment: One thing I can see that discreteness property is not satisfied we can show that there exists infinitely many irrational numbers between any two rationals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Bbb Q^n$ cannot be finitely generated as an abelian group (for $n\geq 1$). For simplicity assume that $n=1$, the general case is similar. Let $r_1,\dots,r_k$ be rational numbers and $d\in\Bbb Z$ a common denominator of them. Then it is clear that the (additive) subgroup of $\Bbb Q$ generated by the $r_1,\dots,r_k$ consists only of numbers which can be written as a fraction with $d$ in the denominator. So $r_1,\dots,r_k$ cannot generate $\Bbb Q$.
So $\Bbb Q^n$ is a non-finitely generated abelian group, hence it is in particular not possible to write $\Bbb Q^n$ as the $\Bbb Z$-span of finitely many linearly independent vectors in $\Bbb R^n$.